# How to display a line break with outputText?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, line-breaks

I need to render a line break using `outputText` so that I can utilize the `rendered` attributed. I tried

```
<h:outputText value="<br/>" escape="false" />
```

but it generated exception

```
The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

That's indeed not valid since Facelets because it's syntactically invalid in XML. You'd need to manually escape the XML special characters like `<`, `>` and so on.

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
```

You can however just emit the `<br/>` in template text without the need for a `<h:outputText>`.

```
<br/>
```

To render it conditionally, wrap it in for example a `<ui:fragment>`.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.rendered}"><br /></ui:fragment>
```

A `<h:panelGroup>` is also valid as it doesn't emit anything to the HTML anyway.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.rendered}"><br /></h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: how would you do this when dynamically adding an `HtmlOutputText` in a managed bean? I tried `HtmlOutputText linebreak = new HtmlOutputText(); lineBreak.setValue("&lt;br/&gt;" and "<br/>");` (obviously not at the same time like that) but neither worked, they simply outputted the text entered, not a break

Comment: @Austin: Apparently you forgot calling `setEscape(false)`.

Comment: sure you don't need any new books? =)

Comment: Thank you BalusC!  If your text with line-breaks comes from an EL expression, you need to use an **UN**-escaped line-break element.

Answer (score 5):

JSF PAGE

```
<h:outputText value="#{car.crg}" escape="false" style="white-space: pre-wrap;word-wrap: break-word; " />
```

**escape** should be `false` and write the bean `Getter` method  as follows

```
 public String getCrg() {
         return crg.replace("<br/>", "&lt;br /&gt;");
        //return crg;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the `"<br />"` inside a resource bundle and then get the value from that resource bundle.