# PrimeFaces inplace cannot display the break line as \n or \r\n

Tags: primefaces

UI Page:

```
<p:inplace id="basic">
            <p:inputText value="#{job.jobContent}" />
</p:inplace>
```

Java code:

```
job.jobContent = "title \r\n body \r\n end.";
```

The web page cannot show the line breaks, how to implement this?

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337331/how-to-display-a-line-break-with-outputtext ....Try like this job.jobContent = "title &lt;br /&gt; body &lt;br /&gt; end."

Comment: Plain `p:inputText` cannot either, not can an `h:inputText`. Either encode then or use a textarea

Comment: I tried replace all "\r\n" to "" as below code:
value="#{fn:replace(task.description,'\\n','&lt;br/&gt;')}" autoResize="false" escape="false"/>
But the output text didn't got it, just show </br>.
How about the encode? I will try it.

Comment: Still didn't work! Thanks